# Magento Layered Navigation block. Move to center

Tags: magento, block, layered-navigation

In `category.xml` I'm changing the reference name in:

```
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

To `content` which I assumed would place the layered `nav` into the center. However, it still stays on the left. In fact, even I changed `left` to `right`, and it still doesn't move from the left sidebar.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to fix this (for anyone else who encounters this problem) by commenting out or deleting the below call in `catelog.xml`:

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Then adding this line within the `name="product_list"` block just below.

```
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="filter" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
```

Then within `list.phtml` echo it like: `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('filter');?>`

Answer (score 1):

Could you please provide more information like in which package/theme you are doing this change and if that package/theme is also actually selected in the admin.

It could also be a caching issue, when its enabled. Have you tried flushing it in `System > Cache management` ?

Perhaps a bit of topic: but best practice is to always do XML layout changes via the local.xml file instead of directly in for example `base/default` XML files. But perhaps you already knew about this.

Comment: This issue seemed to effected all themes (including default) so that ruled out a theme issue, it wasn't a cache issue, i cleared and checked that, which ruled that out. I tired editing the local.xml & the 'base/default' 1. I should of mentioned this is on the Enterprise version. Thxs for answer though. I'll post below how i managed to fix this