# sub categories prouduct not displyed on magento theme home page

Tags: magento

I am customizing magneto modern theme and added several categories and product in main website store. all categories and sub categories are showing on product page but not on home page.. i edited navigation css in styles.css for better look to theme.i stucked.

Answer (score 0):

On the home does not come natively, you need to add to xml

for 2 columns with right bar

```
<reference name="right">
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

for 2 columns with left bar

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Comment: I dont' need a bar on home because i am customizing theme to full scale and left or right bar does not allow content to be full scale no home page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657433/magento-layered-navigation-block-move-to-center
You will need then use the call in xml and php the getChildHtml

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure the attributes "Include in Navigation Menu" & "Is Anchor" are set to "yes" for these categories in backend.

Comment: Yes Both are set to true.

Comment: Hey Nirmal, Can you share me the frontend url is if possible, it will help to understand the issue if its css level or backend level.

Comment: Hey i am learning magento and i am working on localhost so can't share link with you.